# Server load difference between an http response with a single value or an object containing more data

Tags: rest, http, networking, response, restful-architecture

I want to naI want to know if there is a real practical difference between different types of content in an HTTP response. Let me explain my self better.

Say I submit a POST request to a server with typical resource payload. Let's  use a client with client_name, client_email, client_phone.

Would there be an actual difference if the server returns just an id:

```
{id:100}
```

Or if it returns the fully created resource without sensible data, like so:

```
{client_name: 'Some Client', client_email: 'email@sample.com', client_phone: '417-235-4622'}
```

Suppose that the application as a considerable amount of active users, creating resources at any given moment. Is there a significant cost in server resources associated with returning data from the server (just an ID or a full object)

Given the following scenarios when creating a resource:

1. Submit POST request, receive resource ID, complete all data visualization feedback with data in memory (info in form element).
2. Submit POST request, receive full object with id, email and phone. Continue with UI things.

If there is a difference in cost, and its significant, then the response ID is the way to go. But, I'm thinking that if I have lot's fields to submit, and most of them are required, and I'm only expecting an ID in return, then that'a a guarantee that te resource got created but it doesn't mean it was created completely. Suppose I submit the data, and one of those fields fails silently to submit to database (email for example), the server returns ID, the UI shows the user that the resource was created, the user reloads the page and the email is gone.

If the server returns the full object I get the feeling that the transaction is more atomic.

So, to wrap up. Is there a significante difference in terms of cost to the server ?

Comment: There's no point in the server merely sending back what the client already sent in the request. Unless you can come up with a better example it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP Say I have a list of clients displayed for the user, when I create a new client I want to append it to that list.

Answer (score 0):

> but it doesn't mean it was created completely. Suppose I submit the data, and one of those fields fails silently to submit to database (email for example)

Even if the email were to be saved in a different table than the rest of the data, it will still have to be done in a transactional manner (an indivisible operation that must succeed or fail as a complete unit; it can never be only partially complete). This could even mean rolling back changes if a failure is detected at any point during the save operation.

Now back to the main question, REST just says that you should conform to the uniform interface.  In other words, it says you should do what POST is supposed to do as per the [HTTP spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).  Here is the quote from that spec that is relevant,

> If a resource has been created on the
>   origin server, the response    SHOULD
>   be 201 (Created) and contain an entity
>   which describes the    status of the
>   request and refers to the new
>   resource, and a Location    header
>   (see section 14.30).

I think it all depends on the use case scenarios. If the client immediately needs to display info regarding the newly created object, I really do not see any advantage to returning only the ID and doing a GET request after, to get the data you could have got with your initial POST.

Anyway as long as your API is consistent I think that you should choose the pattern that fits your needs the best. There is not any correct way of how to build a REST API, imo.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a significante difference in terms of cost to the server ?

That's totally unanswerable by us. How powerful is the server? What software are you running on it? What's the breakdown of your expected traffic? What performance targets are you expected to hit? etc..

Performance problems should be solved through a combination of more better hardware and a sensible software architecture that still does everything you need it to. You don't even know if you have a problem yet and you're trying to fix it.

You're asking the wrong question. The question you should be asking is: when my clients create a user, are they likely to need server-created information beyond the URI immediately? Of course, we can't really answer that either. If the server isn't (and won't ever!) be creating anything, there's an obvious answer. If it is, or may, you may want to return a full representation even if the client doesn't need it now, so it's not a breaking change later if they decide they do. The pain there depends a lot on whether this is an internal- or external-facing API, and who owns the clients.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers given, which are quite comprehensive, I would just like to add that it is contrary to the design of the web to provide object IDs and expect the client to know what to do with them. You should instead be providing URLs to the object in question. Clients can then do a GET request on the provided URL to fetch the full set of data for the object, should they want to. And I f the responses to these GET requests have already been cached, your server will not have to do any work at all to satisfy them!